# Liferay 7.2, how add route to Blogs portlet

Tags: routes, liferay, liferay-7

I want to add a route to Blogs portlet.

Right now I have:
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home/-/blogs/test

But I want to achieve this:
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/notizia/-/news/test

How I can do that?

I tried to do a hook but i don't know how create a hook for routes of if it is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things to do here:

1. change the path to the page (the part after `/web/guest`) URL from `home` to `notizia`. To do this you need to go to "page configuration" and change the value in "Friendly URL" field. Alternatively you can create another page called `notizia` and place the blog application there.
2. change/add [friendly URL](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/frameworks/-/knowledge_base/f/creating-friendly-urls) for the blogs application to take care of `/blogs/test` part. It will take to too long to explain in details how to do it here but the documentation linked above and [this code sample](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.2#friendly-url) should provide you with enough information how to do it.